# Is there a way to check the full learnt function by Neural Network, not only the weights?

Tags: neural-networks, weights

The training is mostly learning about the wights.But what about the full function learnt by NN? In typical deep learning framework, is there a way to example the function learnt? For example:

```
Y = w1x1 + w2X2 ...wnxn
```

More specifically, for a model structure like the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

How would the function learnt look like?

Comment: The answer below is excellent to my question, and I am not sure why you guys put it on hold. Ridiculous. Jan's answer exactly addressed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way to write down the function explicitly. Each of the layers represents quite simple math operation, which are then just combined together. For example, "dense" layer represents matrix multiplication and vector addition:

$$
\vec{y} = W\vec{x}+\vec{b}
$$

ReLU activation represents just taking positive part of each of the vector components:

$$
y_i = \mathrm{max}(x_i, 0)
$$

Put these together and you realize that your example network represents the following function:

$$
\vec{y} = W_3\left(\sigma\left(W_2\left(\sigma\left(W_1\vec{x}+\vec b_1\right)\right)+\vec b_2\right)\right)+\vec{b}_3 \,,
$$
where $\sigma$ represents ReLU operation.

The more layers you add, the fussier the expression gets, which is why we don't usually write these expressions down explicitly.

Comment: Great. BTW, how do you type those special math symbols in the formula?